# Inner tube problem

Tags: mountain-bike

I ride on and off road on my MTB and most time I've had problems with those little dry spiky things from the bushes(sorry I don't know what they're called). I've had 2 flat tires so far and it's always those pesky spiky things that puncture through the tire and the inner tube. What kind/brand of inner tube do you folks recommend that can withstand riding over these summer dried spiky things on the dirt bike paths? tire size is: 29 X 1.95.

Comment: They sell tires with Kevlar belts to help prevent this and thorn-proof tubes. You may want to try one or both of them. Unfortunately, specific product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Dang nature, messin up your ride!

Comment: Product recommendations are [off topic](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. However, you can still find a number of questions about puncture resistant tubes and tires if you [search the site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=puncture+resistant).

Answer (score 2):

Those darn spiky things are called thorns. Where I'm from there are cactuses that hide in the grass in some places and are notorious for puncturing bike tires. The solution is to use tire sealant in your tubes. Out here most people use ["Slime,"](http://slime.com) you can buy slime brand tubes or just buy the slime and inject it in through your valve. It works almost instantly, I've seen it in action: people run over cactuses, there's an initial hiss of air for a split second, but then it stops all of a sudden as the slime gets in the hole and forms a patch.

Comment: I second this. Slime pre-filled tubes are amazing.

Comment: Sealant filled tubes offer only one advantage over a tubeless setup.  They are cheaper.  A tubeless setup offers several advantages over a sealant filled tube, however.

Comment: @chris *Significantly* cheaper. As in buy a new wheelset or conversion kit (if your wheels are compatible) as well as a new set of tires. Hundreds of dollars vs. paying an extra $7 per tube.

Comment: I think most wheels are compatible with a little work and inexpensive materials.  My fatbike has tubeless tires on a wheelset I personally drilled 100+ holes in the rims.  I also have an old snowcat wheelset that was converted to tubeless.

Comment: @chris I ride tubeless, but most people don't. Those that do wouldn't have to ask this question. Those that don't aren't likely to switch just because of thorns.

Comment: Most people also ride with their seat height improperly adjusted.  That doesn't mean they should.  ANY reason to switch to tubeless is a good reason because it is a better solution for riding bikes.  Anyone asking this question should understand there is a much better solution to their problem out there so they can make an informed decision before purchasing expensive puncture resistant anything.

Comment: @chris That's a poor comparison. Seat hight is an adjustment, going tubeless  is a very expensive upgrade  compared to sliming your tires. The first shop I worked in we charged $5 per wheel to inject slime into tires.

Answer (score 1):

There are various manufacturers out there who offer puncture resistant tires and liners.  All of them sacrifice weight for puncture resistance.

I would highly recommend you look into running tubeless tires.  When you pick up thorns, you can simply remove them, spin the wheel, add some air (if needed) and keep riding.  They require much less effort if you ride in areas with lots of thorns.